# If $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ is Borel measurable, then can we write $A$ as a union of disjoint intervals?

Tags: functional-analysis

If $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ is Borel measurable, then can we write $A$ as a union of disjoint intervals?

I want to calculate the measure of $A$ and it is convenient for me to do it on intervals. Is it possible to decompose $A$ into intervals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

I suppose that you mean "*countable union of disjoint intervals*" ! What do you think about $\mathbb R\backslash \mathbb Q\cap [0,1]$ ?

Comment: What does "Borel measurable" mean? Does that mean $A\subset \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Not that $A\subset \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ but that $A\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$. @Kenneth.K